# Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error

Tags: python

I’m trying to send a large parquet file to RDS Postgres using Lambda. When I try to test the lambda function. I’m facing the below error:
`Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error`
I tried sending with limited rows, I haven’t faced any issue but when I tried to send the whole file which is of 300 mb, then I’m getting the above error.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: In my case, VPC attachment was in progress.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error, which was weird because it was working fine for very small files. I tried with a larger file (only 5mb), and got the error message.

**Solution**: check the memory allocation for the lambda function. I was using the standard minimum (128mb). Changed it to 1gb, it worked fine. The error message is horrible.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem for me. I maxed it out at 3GB and it still didn't run, and I am not anticipating it to need even 1GB for what I'm running.

Comment: @pc_pyr I'm sorry, I don't recall the specific problem I was facing at the time so I don't know if I solved it.

Comment: I am using the recently introduced container image functionality and I faced this same error. I increased the memory to 5 GB and that resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when the Lambda function was inside a VPC and couldn't mount my EFS volume via File System Config. This was with a totally empty new function, no code yet.

No solution yet but that might get you started down the correct path.

Comment: i think i have same issue

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when running tests through the console on lambda functions with very large return statements. I *think* it might be due to the return value overflowing what the test runner can handle. I checked the logs for the function and saw that it was running and exiting successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error every time I set up a Lambda, and then it disappears over the space of a day. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

this error is for your internet connection ( broking the internet connection in the middle of invoking it could be requesting time-out limit on your network)

- it can be your VPN if you are using VPN! ( specify VPN with v2ray protocols they have HTTP request time-out limit)
- as @Daniel R Carletti pointed increasing the RAM will fix it but the issue is not the RAM, it's your internet connection with this solution you will decrease your runtime and as result, you won't face your network time-out.
- the best way to test it if you can not change your network time-out can be to invoke your lambda function inside an EC2.

Answer (score -2):

Update your browser to latest version. Some browsers with additional built-in features may block necessary script on web page.